# Zoom In shortcut does not work in the dev tool interface of most browsers

Tags: shortcut, web-browser

On macOS Ventura, in the dev tools of most browsers, it’s not possible to zoom in with the <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> shortcut unless you use the <kbd>+</kbd> of the numpad which most Macs don’t have.

Curiously, the <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> shortcut for zooming out and <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> for resetting zoom both work as expected.

Tested with Firefox Developer Edition, Tor, Opera, Chrome, and Brave.

Only Safari does not have this problem.

Any idea how to solve this issue for other browsers?

Remember that I’m talking about the zoom command in the development tool interface (<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>), not on a web page.

---

**Edit**

1. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⌃</kbd> works in all browsers except Firefox.
2. I am wondering if the <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> shortcut is not working because on my keyboard, the <kbd>+</kbd> key is shifted (i.e. I need to press <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> to obtain <kbd>+</kbd>). So if someone has a keyboard on which the <kbd>+</kbd> key is not shifted (e.g. Spanish keyboard), can you tell me in the comment if the <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> shortcut works for you.

Comment: Make you you have set the right keyboard shortcut for this action in the browsers?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Check in the browser settings it should be there. I don't use other browsers than Safari so can't try rn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Activate the console by clicking on it.
2. To zoom in the console use <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>.
3. To zoom out press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

To normally zoom in the browser use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> because to get <kbd>+</kbd> you need 'shift' and the ';'.

Thank you @nico for the kbd tag suggestion. Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you @deepyes02, but I cannot reproduce the desired behaviour. Can you edit your answer and surround the keyboard keys with the `<kbd></kbd>` tags?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have updated the keys hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you @deepyes02. The keyboard shortcut `⌘ ⌃` works in all browsers except Firefox. Still I accept your answer as it is indeed very helpful.